# Overlap two 1d-grids and use relative position to do calculations with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Consider a 1 dimensional fixed time grid with `T0 < T1 < T2 < ... < Tn` consisting of `N` intervals with mesh size `s` where `s = Ti+1 - Ti`.
Next, I have another 1 dimensional variable time grid with random time values. Both dimensions have the same unity.
Starting from a given time grid point `Ti`, I want to determine the next variable time. In addition, I want to work backwards and look for the next variable time.
Visually it looks as follows:

[image]

Let's create the two time values:

```
import numpy as np

variable_times = [0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 1.1, 2.75, 5, 5.45, 5.65, 5,8, 7.5, 7.9, 9.1, 9.55, 9.9]
fixed_times = list(np.arange(0, 10, 0.5))
```

So, not for every fixed time there is a corresponding variable time. My desired output is an object with the fixed times and for each fixed time a lower variable time and higher variable time if applicable.

I tried [numpy searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html#numpy.searchsorted) and came up with the following:

```
inds = np.searchsorted(variable_times, fixed_times, side='right')
for n in range(1, fixed_times.size):
   print(variable_times[inds[n]-1], "<=", fixed_times[n], "<", variable_times[inds[n]])
```

However, now some variable times will be used multiple times.

```
0.2 <= 0.5 < 0.8
0.9 <= 1.0 < 1.1
1.1 <= 1.5 < 2.75
1.1 <= 2.0 < 2.75
1.1 <= 2.5 < 2.75
2.75 <= 3.0 < 5.0
2.75 <= 3.5 < 5.0
2.75 <= 4.0 < 5.0
2.75 <= 4.5 < 5.0
5.0 <= 5.0 < 5.45
5.0 <= 5.5 < 8.0
5.0 <= 6.0 < 8.0
5.0 <= 6.5 < 8.0
5.0 <= 7.0 < 8.0
7.5 <= 7.5 < 7.9
7.9 <= 8.0 < 9.1
7.9 <= 8.5 < 9.1  
7.9 <= 9.0 < 9.1
9.1 <= 9.5 < 9.55
```

I only want to use them once. I create a mask to identify all the same bins.

```
mask = np.ediff1d(inds)
mask = np.insert(mask, 0, 1) # add one element to make sure the arrays have the same length
inds = np.where(mask, inds, None)

for n in range(1, fixed_times.size):
   try:
      prev = variable_times[inds[n]-1]
   except:
      prev = None
   try:
      nxt = variable_times[inds[n]+0]
   except:
      nxt = None
print(prev, "<=", fixed_times[n], "<", nxt)
```

This gives the following output:

```
0.2 <= 0.5 < 0.8    # correct
0.9 <= 1.0 < 1.1    # correct
1.1 <= 1.5 < 2.75   # incorrect; 1.1 is double and 2.75 should be assigned to fixed time 2.5 
None <= 2.0 < None  # correct
None <= 2.5 < None  # correct
2.75 <= 3.0 < 5.0   # incorrect; 5 should be assigned to fixed time 5
None <= 3.5 < None  # correct
None <= 4.0 < None  # correct
None <= 4.5 < None  # correct 
5.0 <= 5.0 < 5.45   # incorrect; 5.45 should be assigned to 5.5
5.0 <= 5.5 < 8.0    # incorrect; 5 is double and 8 is not a fixed time?
None <= 6.0 < None  # correct  
None <= 6.5 < None  # correct
None <= 7.0 < None  # correct
7.5 <= 7.5 < 7.9    # incorrect; 7.9 should be assigned to 8 and therefore None
7.9 <= 8.0 < 9.1    # incorrect; 9.1 should be assigned to 9
None <= 8.5 < None  # correct
None <= 9.0 < None  # incorrect; None -> 9.1
9.1 <= 9.5 < 9.55   # incorrect; 9.1 -> None
```

How to make that final step to make sure that the value are located to the correct period? Thanks in advance

Comment: Never mind all that - where is the code to draw the sketch!? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use every element of `variable_times` only once then only a small subset of `fixed_times` will actually be bracketed (have a corresponding higher and lower value).

If I understand correctly, what you want is something similar to this:

```
import numpy as np

variable_times = [0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 1.1, 2.75, 5, 5.45, 5.65, 5,8, 7.5, 7.9, 9.1, 9.55, 9.9]
fixed_times = list(np.arange(0, 10, 0.5))

for time in fixed_times:
    if variable_times[0] <= time < variable_times[1]:
        print(variable_times[0], "<=", time, "<", variable_times[1])
        variable_times = variable_times[2:]
```

Which would produce the following output:

```
0.2 <= 0.5 < 0.8
0.8 <= 1.0 < 1.1
2.75 <= 3.0 < 5
5.45 <= 5.5 < 5.65
5 <= 6.0 < 8
7.5 <= 7.5 < 7.9
9.1 <= 9.5 < 9.55
```